# How can I chance the page orientation of a Crystal report from Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I've created a Crystal report in Visual Studio 2008; but I'm unable to change page orientation to Horizontal.

Comment: go to page setup and change the orientation

Comment: Thanks, Siva. This is what I finally did: right click on the report, Printer settings, select the orientation. My problem was that I didn't have the "Printer settings" on the VS menu - it was gone for some reason.